# laravel @yield does not work in @include

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to add class to an included part of html

```
/* file1.blade.php */

<div class="@yield('myclass')"></div>


/* file2.blade.php */

@include('file1')
@section('myclass', 'foo')
```

But **@yield** does not seem to work for **@includes**. Is there any other way to accomplish this? I cannot use **@extends** as it breaks the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple variable to be your class, and pass it in your include, as the second parameter.

```
/* file1.blade.php */

<div class="{{ $myClass }}"></div>


/* file2.blade.php */

@include('file1', ['myClass' => 'foo'])
```